# Synchronous cross domain jquery call, timeout defect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

on the [internet](http://ph1g.blogspot.com/2010/09/async-getjson-jquery-call.html) i found this little piece of jquery magic, **which does a synchronous cross domain json call.**

For testing The called URL (http://localhost:8080/runsforever) does not return, it runs forever. (endless loop)

I have added the timeout property, but it doesn't work, it blocks for ever.

How to get timeout to work?

```
var jsonObjectInstance = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/inbound-servletapi/getRecommendations",
    timeout: 5 ,
    async : false,
    dataType : 'json'

}).responseText);
```

Comment: You realize the jQuery timeout just uses `setTimeout` which won't work if the request is synchronous?